# Facebook Comments problem

Tags: ajax, facebook, comments

Could anyone tell me why Facebook comments are not working properly?

50% of the time no comments show up initially, with multiple errors in the response ajax from facebook.
99% of the time it's impossible to delete a comment without getting a "Bad Parameter" message.
50% of the time it's impossible to post a comment without getting a "Database Down" message.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I have tried copying example code exactly and other methods with no luck...

About: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Comments_Box

Comment: Checked your configuration properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Facebook API and comments box are both unreliable. fb:comments I've found to be particularly bad (often not loading at all) whether using the FBML or the XFBML versions. I think if it works some of the time for you then it's unlikely that it's anything in your configuration or setup.

Sorry.